# Why does a semicolon return an empty string in IPython?

Tags: python, ipython

When running IPython, if you evaluate a semicolon you get a return value of the empty string, as shown below. Why?

My theory is that it's IPython stripping out the line terminator in the statement but that still doesn't explain why it returns a string.

```
ipython
```

Output:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 11 2016, 05:24:00)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

Session:

```
In [1]: ;
Out[1]: ''
```

This also works in IPython for Python 3.

This doesn't work in the standard Python shell, only in IPython.

Comment: clearly not working for standard Python 3

Comment: and funnily enough: `In [1]: ;;` -> `Out[1]: ';'` and `In [2]: ;;;` -> `Out[2]: ';;'` ?! i had thought the idea of `;` in ipython was to suppress the 'implicit' output.

Comment: In ipython you can force automatic quoting of a function’s arguments by using , or ; as the first character of a line . see this [doc](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactive/reference.html#automatic-parentheses-and-quotes)

Comment: It's the line end `;` that suppresses output; but the line start `;` acts first, and neutralizes any following `;` by quoting it.

Comment: I would argue that the question is different from the proposed duplicate—though the answer is very similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IPython has special handling for semicolons at the start of the line.  For example:

```
In [1]: ;ord A   # autocall -- calls function "ord" on string "A"
Out[1]: 65
```

It looks like if it can't parse a function name, you get buggy behavior:

```
In [4]: ;;;
Out[4]: ';;'

In [5]: ;?huh
Out[5]: '?huh'

In [6]: ;?huh?
Object `huh` not found.

In [7]: ;?huh
Out[7]: '?huh;?huh'

In [8]:
```

(The above is with IPython 2.4.1 running Python 3.5.2.)

So I wouldn't try to interpret it as "stripping out a line terminator" or trying to relate it back to Python syntax.

Comment: Cool! Is the semicolon syntax documented somewhere?

Comment: @tihom pointed out one place where it's documented.  I spotted in buried way down in IPython's built-in `%quickref` in the "Autocall" section.

Comment: Nevermind. I missed @tihom's comment pointing me here: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactive/reference.html#automatic-parentheses-and-quotes

Comment: It is probably using a simple test to decide whether the first string is a (potential) variable (or number).   Failing that it just quotes the whole thing.  Letter, number or _ trigger the callable, anything else is quoted.